# Gradle init on FIPS-enabled RHEL8 and AmazonLinux 2023 failing with PKCS#11

Tags: java, gradle, fips, softhsm

I have set up PKCS#11 via SoftHSM v2.6.1, and installed OpenJDK 17 on both RHEL8 and AL2023 EC2 instances that are FIPS-enabled.  Every time I run anything with gradle, even `gradle init`, I get a `CKR_GENERAL_ERROR` because `P11Digest.engineUpdate` fails.  My ~/.pkcs11/pkcs11.cfg is:

```
name = SoftHSM
library = /usr/lib64/pkcs11/libsofthsm2.so
slotListIndex = 0
showInfo = true
```

My java.security providers section is:

```
security.provider.1=SunPKCS11 ${user.home}/.pkcs11/pkcs11.cfg
security.provider.2=SUN
security.provider.3=SunRsaSign
security.provider.4=SunEC
security.provider.5=SunJSSE
security.provider.6=SunJCE
security.provider.7=SunJGSS
security.provider.8=SunSASL
security.provider.9=XMLDSig
security.provider.10=SunPCSC
security.provider.11=JdkLDAP
security.provider.12=JdkSASL
```

My ~/.gradle/gradle.properties is a bit overkill, but any combination of these options still results in the same issue:

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11 \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NONE \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=1234 \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=PKCS11 \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider=SunPKCS11-SoftHSM \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=NONE \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=1234 \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS11 \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider=SunPKCS11-SoftHSM
systemProp.java.security.debug=sunpkcs11
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NONE
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=1234
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=PKCS11
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider=SunPKCS11-SoftHSM
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.keyStore=NONE
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=1234
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS11
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider=SunPKCS11-SoftHSM
```

When I run `gradle init`, I get this output (including the info from when it accesses SoftHSM):

```
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Information for provider SunPKCS11-SoftHSM
Library info:
  cryptokiVersion: 2.40
  manufacturerID: SoftHSM                         
  flags: 0
  libraryDescription: Implementation of PKCS11        
  libraryVersion: 2.06
All slots: 952201258, 1
Slots with tokens: 952201258, 1
Slot info for slot 952201258:
  slotDescription: SoftHSM slot ID 0x38c1702a                                      
  manufacturerID: SoftHSM project                 
  flags: CKF_TOKEN_PRESENT
  hardwareVersion: 2.06
  firmwareVersion: 2.06
Token info for token in slot 952201258:
  label: My token 1                      
  manufacturerID: SoftHSM project                 
  model: SoftHSM v2      
  serialNumber: 610dbc50b8c1702a
  flags: CKF_RNG | CKF_LOGIN_REQUIRED | CKF_USER_PIN_INITIALIZED | CKF_RESTORE_KEY_NOT_NEEDED | CKF_TOKEN_INITIALIZED
  ulMaxSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulSessionCount: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulMaxRwSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulRwSessionCount: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulMaxPinLen: 255
  ulMinPinLen: 4
  ulTotalPublicMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulFreePublicMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulTotalPrivateMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulFreePrivateMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  hardwareVersion: 2.06
  firmwareVersion: 2.06
  utcTime: 2024012821575000
Mechanism CKM_AES_CBC:
  ulMinKeySize: 16
  ulMaxKeySize: 32
  flags: 131840 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT | CKF_WRAP
Mechanism CKM_AES_CBC_ENCRYPT_DATA:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 524288 = CKF_DERIVE
Mechanism CKM_AES_CBC_PAD:
  ulMinKeySize: 16
  ulMaxKeySize: 32
  flags: 768 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT
Mechanism CKM_AES_CMAC:
  ulMinKeySize: 16
  ulMaxKeySize: 32
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_AES_CTR:
  ulMinKeySize: 16
  ulMaxKeySize: 32
  flags: 768 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT
Mechanism CKM_AES_ECB:
  ulMinKeySize: 16
  ulMaxKeySize: 32
  flags: 768 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT
Mechanism CKM_AES_ECB_ENCRYPT_DATA:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 524288 = CKF_DERIVE
Mechanism CKM_AES_GCM:
  ulMinKeySize: 16
  ulMaxKeySize: 32
  flags: 768 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT
Mechanism CKM_AES_KEY_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 16
  ulMaxKeySize: 32
  flags: 32768 = CKF_GENERATE
Mechanism CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP:
  ulMinKeySize: 16
  ulMaxKeySize: 2147483648
  flags: 393216 = CKF_WRAP | CKF_UNWRAP
Mechanism CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP_PAD:
  ulMinKeySize: 1
  ulMaxKeySize: 2147483648
  flags: 393216 = CKF_WRAP | CKF_UNWRAP
Mechanism CKM_DES2_KEY_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 32768 = CKF_GENERATE
Mechanism CKM_DES3_CBC:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 131840 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT | CKF_WRAP
Mechanism CKM_DES3_CBC_ENCRYPT_DATA:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 524288 = CKF_DERIVE
Mechanism CKM_DES3_CBC_PAD:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 768 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT
Mechanism CKM_DES3_CMAC:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_DES3_ECB:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 768 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT
Mechanism CKM_DES3_ECB_ENCRYPT_DATA:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 524288 = CKF_DERIVE
Mechanism CKM_DES3_KEY_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 32768 = CKF_GENERATE
Mechanism CKM_DES_CBC:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 131840 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT | CKF_WRAP
Mechanism CKM_DES_CBC_ENCRYPT_DATA:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 524288 = CKF_DERIVE
Mechanism CKM_DES_CBC_PAD:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 131840 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT | CKF_WRAP
Mechanism CKM_DES_ECB:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 131840 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT | CKF_WRAP
Mechanism CKM_DES_ECB_ENCRYPT_DATA:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 524288 = CKF_DERIVE
Mechanism CKM_DES_KEY_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 32768 = CKF_GENERATE
Mechanism CKM_DH_PKCS_DERIVE:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 10000
  flags: 524288 = CKF_DERIVE
Mechanism CKM_DH_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 10000
  flags: 65536 = CKF_GENERATE_KEY_PAIR
Mechanism CKM_DH_PKCS_PARAMETER_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 10000
  flags: 32768 = CKF_GENERATE
Mechanism CKM_DSA:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 1024
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_DSA_KEY_PAIR_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 1024
  flags: 65536 = CKF_GENERATE_KEY_PAIR
Mechanism CKM_DSA_PARAMETER_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 1024
  flags: 32768 = CKF_GENERATE
Mechanism CKM_DSA_SHA1:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 1024
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_DSA_SHA224:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 1024
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_DSA_SHA256:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 1024
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_DSA_SHA384:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 1024
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_DSA_SHA512:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 1024
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_ECDH1_DERIVE:
  ulMinKeySize: 112
  ulMaxKeySize: 521
  flags: 524288 = CKF_DERIVE
Mechanism CKM_ECDSA:
  ulMinKeySize: 112
  ulMaxKeySize: 521
  flags: 26224640 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY | CKF_EC_F_P | CKF_EC_UNCOMPRESS
Mechanism CKM_EC_EDWARDS_KEY_PAIR_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 256
  ulMaxKeySize: 456
  flags: 65536 = CKF_GENERATE_KEY_PAIR
Mechanism CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 112
  ulMaxKeySize: 521
  flags: 26279936 = CKF_GENERATE_KEY_PAIR | CKF_EC_F_P | CKF_EC_UNCOMPRESS
Mechanism CKM_EDDSA:
  ulMinKeySize: 256
  ulMaxKeySize: 456
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_GENERIC_SECRET_KEY_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 1
  ulMaxKeySize: 2147483648
  flags: 32768 = CKF_GENERATE
Mechanism CKM_MD5:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 1024 = CKF_DIGEST
Mechanism CKM_MD5_HMAC:
  ulMinKeySize: 16
  ulMaxKeySize: 512
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_MD5_RSA_PKCS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_RSA_PKCS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 404224 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT | CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY | CKF_WRAP | CKF_UNWRAP
Mechanism CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 65536 = CKF_GENERATE_KEY_PAIR
Mechanism CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 393984 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT | CKF_WRAP | CKF_UNWRAP
Mechanism CKM_RSA_PKCS_PSS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_RSA_X_509:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 11008 = CKF_ENCRYPT | CKF_DECRYPT | CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS_PSS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA224:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 1024 = CKF_DIGEST
Mechanism CKM_SHA224_HMAC:
  ulMinKeySize: 28
  ulMaxKeySize: 512
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA224_RSA_PKCS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA224_RSA_PKCS_PSS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA256:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 1024 = CKF_DIGEST
Mechanism CKM_SHA256_HMAC:
  ulMinKeySize: 32
  ulMaxKeySize: 512
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS_PSS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA384:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 1024 = CKF_DIGEST
Mechanism CKM_SHA384_HMAC:
  ulMinKeySize: 48
  ulMaxKeySize: 512
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA384_RSA_PKCS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA384_RSA_PKCS_PSS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA512:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 1024 = CKF_DIGEST
Mechanism CKM_SHA512_HMAC:
  ulMinKeySize: 64
  ulMaxKeySize: 512
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA512_RSA_PKCS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA512_RSA_PKCS_PSS:
  ulMinKeySize: 512
  ulMaxKeySize: 16384
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Mechanism CKM_SHA_1:
  ulMinKeySize: 0
  ulMaxKeySize: 0
  flags: 1024 = CKF_DIGEST
Mechanism CKM_SHA_1_HMAC:
  ulMinKeySize: 20
  ulMaxKeySize: 512
  flags: 10240 = CKF_SIGN | CKF_VERIFY
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
> update() failed

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.VirtualFileSystemServices$GradleUserHomeServices.createResourceSnapshotterCacheService(VirtualFileSystemServices.java:283)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:911)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:838)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:686)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:851)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:837)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:686)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:851)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:837)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:686)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:851)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:837)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:686)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:851)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:837)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:686)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:851)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:837)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:686)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getCollectionService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1141)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getCollectionService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1123)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1086)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1600(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:813)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.prepare(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:700)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:723)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:450)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeServiceProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1008)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1094)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:329)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:323)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:308)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:303)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:58)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: update() failed
        at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.P11Digest.engineUpdate(P11Digest.java:242)
        at java.base/java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate.engineUpdate(MessageDigest.java:658)
        at java.base/java.security.MessageDigest.update(MessageDigest.java:349)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.Hashing$MessageDigestHasher.update(Hashing.java:302)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.Hashing$MessageDigestHasher.putInt(Hashing.java:318)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.Hashing$DefaultHasher.putString(Hashing.java:413)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.Hashing.signature(Hashing.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultResourceSnapshotterCacheService.<clinit>(DefaultResourceSnapshotterCacheService.java:33)
        ... 107 more
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_GENERAL_ERROR
        at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_DigestInit(Native Method)
        at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.P11Digest.engineUpdate(P11Digest.java:224)
        ... 114 more


BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

I keep trying to search for info about this, but I am not coming up with anything.  I am sure that some people are using RHEL8 or AL2023 in FIPS mode and using SoftHSM.  I am new to PKCS#11, and HSMs in general, so I do not know how to diagnose this further.  Thanks in advance for anything that anyone is willing to share.